# Disable Data Loader by Profile

Tags: api, security, profile, data-loader, bulk-api

Is it possible to disable the data loader based on profile (or role)?

We have some non-tech users who like to use the data loader for bulk updates, unfortunately, they are also making mistakes when using it.  I realize that it can be controlled in other ways (disabling API access, removing access to objects).  However, those aren't really options at the moment because they need access to all of the objects (high profile users) and we have an in-house application that makes use of the API within the context of the user (by passing in their session).

Am I stuck on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling API access by profile is the only option here as it relates to the Data Loader.

EDIT: Thinking about your problem more holistically, it seems to me like you need to provide the ability to mass update many different objects in the database and you also need to be able to control the logic pretty tightly. That's a good case for a visualforce page and some batch apex in lieu of the DataLoader.

Comment: I didn't think it would be possible, but, I thought I would ask.  I would like to eventually get to a point where I can remove API access; I think I'll need to re-architect one of our internal apps so that dependency can be removed.  Thanks!